# Performance of JavaScript MD5 checksum generation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, checksum

I am trying to create a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) web site that allows users to upload files along with some form data. To verify file integrity of file uploaded, a client-side JavaScript checksum would be passed up to compare against a server generated checksum. Is the JavaScript checksum generation performance going to hold up if, say, 1-5 of the files are uploading at 1 Gbit/s?

The uploader is based on the project *[ASP.NET Multiple File Upload With Drag & Drop and Progress Bar Using HTML5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460142/ASP-NET-Multiple-File-Upload-With-Drag-Drop-and-Pr)*

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to benchmark this yourself?

Comment: Hi, before I invested too much time, I didn't know if someone would have some input or experience in this area.  Thanks.

Comment: TCP (which HTTP sits on top of) already provides error detection: do you really need to add your own?